# Cómo valido un campo dado el valor de otro campo

Tags: sql, postgresql

Necesito validar el valor de una columna de una tabla.

Tengo las columnas `descripCateg` y `descripSubCategoria`.

`descripCateg` solo puede tomar ciertos valores (para eso hice un *CHECK*), y los posibles valores de `descripSubCategoria` van a depender del valor de la columna `descripCateg`.

Por ejemplo, si `descripCateg` su valor es *Accidentes en el hogar*, entonces `descripSubCategoria`, solo puede tomar uno de los siguientes valores:  *Intoxicaciones*, *quemaduras*, *torceduras*, *herida*.

Pero si el valor de `descripCateg` es *Accidentes en el trabajo*, entonces `descripSubCategoria` solo puede tomar uno de los siguientes valores:
*Quemaduras*, *congelamiento*, *inmersión*, *electrocución*, y así.

Ya tengo lista la columna `descripCateg`, pero no se cómo escribir el ***check constraint*** de `descripSubCategoria` que considere los posibles valores de `descripCateg` y valide que los valores posibles son los que están de acuerdo con el valor de `descripCateg`.

¿Esto se puede hacer con SQL no?

Comment: El modelo de datos que presentas es poco adecuado. Eso debería de estar en otra tabla. Tanto la categoría, como la subcategoría. A partir de estar en otra tabla, ahí ya hay muchas posibilidades. Por ejemplo Tabla `Categorias (id, padre, descripcion)`. Asi una categoría tendrá de padre null y una subcategoría tendrá de padre algún id de la misma tabla. Existen otras muchas maneras, pero en la misma tabla con columnas de tipo texto, no es adecuado. Normaliza el modelo hasta 3ª forma. Hay mucha información sobre como se hace.

Comment: @Javifer2 muchas gracias por tu comentario, le voy a decir a mi profesora de base de datos que el modelo de datos que me pasó no sirve, y que ella no sabe normalizar hasta la 3era forma, saludos

Comment: No veo por ningún lado de tú pregunta, que sea un ejercicio académico. En ese escenario es válido todo, porque de lo que se trata es de aprender, y no de que sea o no adecuado. Ahora bien, puedes revisar los siguientes enlaces del sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic) y leer [ask]